# What is the best way to migrate a .bash_profile to Mavericks

Tags: terminal, macos, bash

I have a pretty extensive .bash_profile set up on my older machine using Lion and I would like to include a lot of the same functionality. I noticed that Mavericks doesn't have a .bash_profile by default.

What is the best practice here?

```
.bashrc
.bash_profile
.profile
```

Should I just create the file, should it be picked up automatically or is there anything else to configure?

Note: This is just for a single user account, so it doesn't have to be set up globally.

Answer (score 1):

Go right ahead and put your old `.bash_profile` file in your home directory and it will get read.

For your purposes `.bash_profile`, `.bash_login` and `.profile` are identical with the exception that one and only one will be read - the first one found of the three with bash searching in that order.

`.bashrc` is only read when you run an interactive shell that is not a login shell.

Comment: Terminal.app by default runs a login shell

Comment: Some more info; on a typical system, `.profile` contains common settings that will be needed regardless of what type of login it is. `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` then both include it and also set their own settings for either a login or interactive shell.